# DataSource stored procedure strange behaviour

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a stored procedure called `ItemGetCategories` and a `SqlDataSource`

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="CategoriesDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="ItemGetCategories" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" OnSelected="CategoriesDataSource_Selected">
       <SelectParameters>
          <asp:RouteParameter Name="StockItemId" RouteKey="id" Type="String" />                                            
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

SQL server is receiving this query from the datasource

```
exec ItemGetCategories @StockItemId=15
```

and nothing is returned to the datasource, executing this query in SQL Server Management Studio also does not return any rows.

Now the strange part, executing this from SQL Server Management Studio returns 1 row.

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[ItemGetCategories]
        @StockItemId = N'15'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

This is the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ItemGetCategories]
    @StockItemId nvarchar(10) = '1'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH categoryPath(Id,Slug,CategoryName)
    AS
    (
        SELECT 
           Id, Slug, CategoryName 
        FROM 
           Categories
        WHERE 
           ParentCategoryId IS NULL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            Categories.Id,
            CAST(categoryPath.Slug + '/' + categories.Slug AS NVARCHAR(150)),
            Categories.CategoryName
        FROM 
            Categories
        JOIN 
            categoryPath ON Categories.ParentCategoryId = categoryPath.Id
     )
     SELECT * 
     FROM [ItemCategories]
     JOIN categoryPath ON [ItemCategories].StockId = categoryPath.Id 
     WHERE [ItemCategories].StockId = @StockItemId
END
```

Why does the stored procedure not return any rows to the datasource?

I have tried to change the stored procedure parameter from int to string and pass the parameter from datasource as string, but still the same result.

Comment: In one example, you're passing StockItemId as a string, and in another as an int.  Could that be the problem?  The definition of the stored procedure parameter should indicate whether it's supposed to be an int32 or an nvarchar variable.

Comment: that is because I have tried different parameter types, but they are both string now and I get the same result

Comment: Actually in the second example you should be getting 2 result sets.  One with no results (which is the result from the select in the stored procedure) and the second with 1.  The second result set is actually just the return value of the stored procedure, which by default is 0.  Can you send the definition of the stored procedure?

Comment: `@StockItemId nvarchar(10) = '1'` doesn't looks correct to me. You defined it as `nvarchar` but assigning it a default `varchar` value. either define it like `@StockItemId varchar(10) = '1'` or `@StockItemId int = 1`. It should work fine then.

Comment: I would recommend getting the select within the stored procedure to work by itself, then go from there.  Start by replacing the ALTER PROCEDURE etc with a DECLARE for the parameter and see if you can get that to work.  If not, something is wrong with the select.

Comment: I have tried to define it as int and changed the datasource parameter to int32 and still not get any result.

Comment: does the select query in procedure really return any data? run it separately and see.

Comment: The stored procedure works, executing from sql studio I get results

Comment: @rahul you beat me to it. Try varchar instead of nvarchar. Nvarchar technically sets the datatype to the same size everytime. My guess is its passing: "15        " which is not the same as "15"

Comment: what datatype is it in the database... your datasource, stored procedure and table all need to be in sync

Comment: I have changed to varchar, but still no result

Comment: what is the datatype of the table itself.

Comment: also try not hardcoding a default value: `@StockItemId nvarchar(10) = '1'`

Comment: This is the exact command received by the SQL server  exec ItemGetCategories @StockItemId=N'15'

Comment: What's the datatype of `[ItemCategories].StockId`?

Comment: I hadcoded the value in the stored procedure and the datasource still does not get any result!

Comment: [ItemCategories].StockIt it's int

Comment: That's a bummer. 1. declare `@StockItemId` to be `INT` then. 2. I doubt your CTE even return any result. try running `select * from categoryPath` and see if it's return any row?

Comment: I have 4 datasources on the page, and all other datasources are working with SELECT commands

Comment: Ok, I have hardcoded the value again with nvarchar and now it returns 1 row to datasource. Now I have to get it working with the parameter

Comment: I have changed all parameters to Int now and it seems to work, I really don't understand what was wrong, because I tried this before and it didn't work.

Comment: @Rahul add an answer so you can get the credit. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your procedure code except the datatype mismatch. Make changes to few things as below.

Change procedure parameter `@StockItemId` to `INT` since `[ItemCategories].StockId` is `INT` type and you are making a filtering based on it `WHERE [ItemCategories].StockId=@StockItemId`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ItemGetCategories]
    @StockItemId INT = NULL
```

Define Datasource property accordingly like

```
<SelectParameters>
<asp:RouteParameter Name="StockItemId" RouteKey="id" Type="INT32" />                                            
</SelectParameters>
```